# Can Java Array objects be created dynamically at Runtime?

Tags: java

Can I do this in Java?

**At Runtime:**

`int length` = some arithmetic that loads length

then  I use length to do this:

```
byte [] b = new byte[length];
```

Will this throw an Exception at Runtime? If so which one?

Comment: Have you tried it? If so, what were the results?

Comment: It doesn't show a compile time error, but I am getting an error at runtime and I don't know whether this is the source?

Comment: You need to investigate the error, not the code.

Comment: There is no magic here. Arrays in Java are just special kinds of objects -- they are *always* created 'dynamically' (even with an integer literal specified). The value passed to their specialized-constructor is just an integer-yielding expression that specifies the size.

Comment: @pst: I have seen lots of code using Static final variables or compile time constants to create array objects like 
static final int LENGTH = 10;
byte[] b = new byte[LENGTH];
Therefore I wondered whether I was on the rigth track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that won't throw an exception at runtime, unless of course length is negative.

Comment: Array sizes and indices are signed integers so anything up to and including Integer.MAX_VALUE is fine. If there's not enough memory, technically you won't get an exception, you get an error (OutOfMemoryError). :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be created at run time.

But you should try and see :)

Comment: Can't,  I am a limited Java platform that doesn't have the ArrayList class.

Comment: Why do you say that you should try and see? Isn't there any concrete documentation on this subject?

Comment: Concrete documentation is reading some books and some tutorials on the net. Your counter question could be? is this true for both Heap and Stack ?

Answer (score 0):

i think you are forgetting the basic concept as objects are created at comile time and memory is allocated at run time.